# full calendar and JSP servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, fullcalendar

there.  For the first time I am trying to integrate full calendar with JSP Servlet and MySQL. For now just trying to get it work without database connection. I can't see events in the calendar...

eventCalendar.jsp

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Timetable</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    <script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here
                events: "calendarServlet",
                dayClick: function () {
                    alert('a day has been clicked!');
                }
            })

        });
    </script>
</head>
```

calendarServlet.java

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 List l = new ArrayList();

 CalendarDTO c = new CalendarDTO();


 c.setId(1);
 c.setStart("2017-01-26");
 c.setEnd("2017-01-27");
 c.setTitle("Task in Progress");

CalendarDTO d = new CalendarDTO();
 c.setId(2);
 c.setStart("2017-01-24");
 c.setEnd("2017-01-25");
 c.setTitle("Task in Progress");

 l.add(c);
 l.add(d);

String json = new Gson().toJson(l);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
 }
```

In Chrome developer tools I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
    at normalizeEventTimes (fullcalendar.js:12272)
    at normalizeEventDates (fullcalendar.js:12252)
    at assignDatesToEvent (fullcalendar.js:12243)
    at buildEventFromInput (fullcalendar.js:12227)
    at fullcalendar.js:11624
    at Object.success (fullcalendar.js:11754)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
normalizeEventTimes @ fullcalendar.js:12272
normalizeEventDates @ fullcalendar.js:12252
assignDatesToEvent @ fullcalendar.js:12243
buildEventFromInput @ fullcalendar.js:12227
(anonymous) @ fullcalendar.js:11624
success @ fullcalendar.js:11754
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
A @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake:

```
CalendarDTO d = new CalendarDTO();
c.setId(2);
c.setStart("2017-01-24");
c.setEnd("2017-01-25");
c.setTitle("Task in Progress");
```

should be

```
CalendarDTO d = new CalendarDTO();
d.setId(2);
d.setStart("2017-01-24");
d.setEnd("2017-01-25");
d.setTitle("Task in Progress");
```